# Excel conditional formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I know I might be pushing limits, but is there a way in Excel to identify letters in a cell and format accordingly? Meaning if I type "TAT 12 hello" in a cell and type "TAT 12 bye" in another, then both the cells should become red, matching the code "TAT 12" as it is in both  the cells. It happens in case of duplicated values using conditional formatting.

Comment: If you can specify the string "TAT 12", then you can do a conditional format against cells containing that string. If you want to match on partial uniqueness, I don't think it can.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using `Conditional Formatting`.

Suppose you want to make any cell red that contains the string `TAT 12` and suppose all your entries are in rows in column A.

Try the following:

1. Select column A
2. Now use menu bar **Format > Conditional Formatting...**
3. In the dialog box select `Formula Is` in the first drop down
4. Now add the formula `=ISNUMBER(FIND("TAT 12",A1))`
5. Select red as the font if the condition is met

In short, the formula uses `Find` to check for `TAT 12` in the cell.

Comment: i would use `=isnumber(find...`

Comment: @deathApril - Nice! that is a more succinct way than I have it. Are you happy for me to update my answer with your idea?